# Continue a while loop on current line

Tags: tcl, expect

I wrote a script that does a lot of commands on cisco devices. If a problem occurs on sw or router and the program stop, I need to remove all lines before the current line.

example:

```
ips.txt
169.254.0.1
169.254.0.2
169.254.0.3 <- For any reason, the program stop here (no login or the device becomes unreachable or anyway)
169.254.0.4
```

After

```
ips.txt
169.254.0.3 <- Run again after treat a problem on device
169.254.0.4
```

How can I do to the loop continue on the same line it stop without remove lines manually?

Here is the loop part:

```
set f [open "ips.txt" r]
set lines [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f
set n [llength $lines]
set i 0

while { $i <= $n } {
        set nl [lindex $lines $i]
        set l3 [split $nl ","]
        set IP_SW [lindex $l3 0]
        set IP_RT [lindex $l3 1]

    do a lot of tcl and expect commands...
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of unnecessary detail in the example. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I think you should try to explain your problem better. You can put how the code is currently working in a few steps (e.g. 1. file is getting read fine, 2. the script loops over each line fine, 3. when xxx happens [...] . What should happen is 1. file gets read. 2 loop over each line, 3. when xx happens [...], etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
set filename ips.txt
set num_processed 0

while {...} {
   # ...
   if {successfully processed this one} {
        incr num_processed
   }
}

# out of the while loop, remove the first N lines from the file
# assuming your system has GNU sed
exec sed -i.bak "1,${num_processed}d" $filename

# or with Tcl
set fin [open $filename]
set fout [open $filename.new w]
set n 0
while {[gets $fin line] != -1} {
    if {[incr n] <= $num_processed} continue
    puts $fout $line
}
file link -hard $filename.bak $filename
file rename -force $filename.new $filename
```

Comment: glenn, Its help me a lot! I will answer to improve more details.

Answer (score 0):

based on glenn's answer, I did this:

```
#inside while loop
while { $i <= $n } {
        set nl [lindex $lines $i]
        set l3 [split $nl ","]
        set IP_SW [lindex $l3 0]
        set IP_RT [lindex $l3 1]

# condition to continue on current line, even the program exit unexpectedly
        set laststop [open "roundline.txt" w]
        puts $laststop "previousround"
        puts $laststop "$IP_SW $IP_RT"
        close $laststop
}

#out of while loop
set laststop [open "roundline.txt" r]
    foreach a [split [read -nonewline $laststop] \n] {
       set LINE [lindex $a 0]
          if { $LINE != "previousround" } {
               exec sed -i "/$LINE\/ipreviousround" ips.txt
               exec sed -i "0,/previousround/d" ips.txt
          }
    }
```

Now, if the program stop for any reason, the file "roundline.txt" will save the last line. Then I insert "previousround" just to match before my line. After that, I remove the first line until "previousround".